# Используется ли бинарный поиск при вставке значения в MySql?

Tags: mysql

Гуглил но так и не понял, как работает вставка значения в таблицу MySql.

Допустим такой запрос:

```
INSERT INTO employee(id, name) VALUES(200, 'Jason');
```

При наличии id=200, вернет исключение:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '200' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Меня интересует как БД узнала о наличии этого ключа? Перебирала все значения в таблице или осуществила бинарный поиск?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз описанный случай касается `primary key`, то логично предположить, что поиск осуществлялся в индексе, следовательно, он не был основан на переборе. Насчёт его бинарности в чистом виде почему-то тоже сомневаюсь, зависит от типа индекса.

Comment: Но после нескольких таких вставок придется выполнять переиндексацию, верно?

Comment: @АлександрЛи После нескольких вставок точно не придется. mysql сам справится с балансировкой дерева в индексе.